# Write binary data to file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, arrays, binaryfiles

I've been having a LOT of trouble with this and the other questions don't seem to be what I'm looking for. So basically I have a list of bytes gotten from

```
bytes = struct.pack('I',4)
bList = list(bytes)
# bList ends up being [0,0,0,4]
# Perform some operation that switches position of bytes in list, etc
```

So now I want to write this to a file

```
f = open('/path/to/file','wb')
for i in range(0,len(bList)):
   f.write(bList[i])
```

But I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

I've also tried writing:

```
bytes(bList[i]) # Seems to write the incorrect number. 
str(bList[i]).encode()   # Seems to just write the string value instead of byte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh boy, I had to jump through hoops to solve this. So basically I had to instead do

```
bList = bytes()
bList += struct.pack('I',4)

# Perform whatever byte operations I need to

byteList = []

# I know, there's probably a list comprehension to do this more elegantly
for i in range(0,len(bList)):
    byteList.append(bList[i])

f.write(bytes(byteList))
```

So bytes can take an array of byte values (even if they're represented in decimal form in the array) and convert it to a proper byteArray by casting